# What is your favorite User Interface? (web application)

Tags: user-interface

I think it would be interesting to get a programmers viewpoint on UI design.

What is your favorite User Interface that you have come across in a web application?

If possible, say a little bit about why you like it.

Answer (score 9):

http://www.google.com is my favorite. Can be considered a "lack of UI" ;)

Comment: It's been my favorite for nearly a decade now.  The must have done something right :)

Answer (score 9):

At the risk of sounding too much of a fan ... I think StackOverflow has a great UI.  It is  clean, without clutter (except the creeping ads!), the navigation is straight forward and yet manages to compress a fair amount of functionality.

Fairly simple features, like the coloured vote buttons to show what you have voted for, and the live preview really add to the interactive feel.

(And I don't mind the ads as long as they stay away from the flashing punch-the-monkey kind!)

Comment: I do think the side ads would be better served as text, or at least a border around the image.

Answer (score 8):

Web application: **Wordpress**.  It's so powerful, yet clean and easy to use.

Desktop application: **Excel** (or equivelent).  Seriously, a spreadsheet is the most innovative and clever user interface ever devised.  It's used for everything.  I don't know what the question is, but the answer is Excel.

Answer (score 6):

GMail interface is so smooth and fast that I question me why nobody had done that before.

Answer (score 4):

[Mint.com](https://mint.intuit.com/), if you trust someone else with your bank account information.  It keeps track of all your transactions, lets you fill out a budget, notifies you of unusual spending trends or transactions, and lets you drill down through your spending trends to see exactly where all of your hard earned cash is going.  Best of all, it's free.

[image: Pie Chart]
<sub>(source: [mint.com](https://www.mint.com/images/about/features/graphs.gif))</sub>

Comment: Maybe compared to a site like this one where the devs are OCD about performance, but it's much faster than my bank's version of a one-stop financial web app.

Comment: Shame it's not available in the UK yet though.

Answer (score 4):

I think [Remember The Milk](http://www.rmilk.com) has a brilliantly clean and intuitive interface

Comment: My favourite UI too, I'd rather use RTM other Google Cal Tasks.

Answer (score 2):

- http://bbc.co.uk homepage
- http://mail.google.com/
- http://stackoverlow.com (that is I liked it before the introduction of ads :)

Answer (score 2):

I think stackoverflow has done a great job in many areas in terms of usability, including colour pallete, use of whitespace, anticipating user's need for information and providing or hiding appropriately, non-intrusive JS/AJAX.

Minus points for these increasingly obtrusive ads, though.  :P

Gmail is also good.  Honourable mention to github.com.

Update: I recently got introduced to [FriendFeed](http://friendfeed.com).  I think they have also done a fabulous job with their web UI, in terms of clean yet attractive design, plus appropriate and helpful use of Javascript and AJAX to provide for a smooth, positive user experience.  Check it out.

Answer (score 2):

[FreshBooks](http://www.freshbooks.com) accounting has a very nice interface.

(Although I upvoted the answer in favor of StackOverflow)

Answer (score 0):

The new Yahoo Mail UI blew me away when I first saw it. The keyboard shortcuts, drag 'n' drop, tabs, etc. really make it look and feel like a desktop app. Admittedly this quality of UI has become a lot more common on the web in the last few years, but for me at least, Yahoo Mail was the first web app in my experience to bring this kind of usability to the web.

Answer (score 0):

- http://fastladder.com has great UI for feedholic. I can't live without fldr's keyboard shortcuts (and some greasemonkey to change them to fit for me.)
- http://www.instapaper.com is also simple and great. This is temporary storage for web resource marked as read later, and don't need password for make account because of that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

For the CLI lovers out there...

http://cb.vu/

cat about.txt

Not really useful but it's quite interesting.